# Show that $z^{w_1}z^{w_2} = z^{w_1+w_2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given that $z,w_1$ and $w_2$ are complex numbers.

Show that $$z^{w_1}z^{w_2} = z^{w_1+w_2}$$ occurs if and only if for any $k_1,k_2\in \mathbb{Z}$, there exist $m,k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$w_1(k_1-m)+w_2(k_2-m)=k$$

Here is my attempt, (I use exp[z] as $e^z$ as the letters in the power of $e$ are too small)

$$z^{w_1} = e^{w_1 \log z} = \exp[w_1(\ln|z| + iArg z + 2k_1\pi i]$$
$$z^{w_2} = e^{w_2 \log z} = \exp[w_2(\ln|z| + iArg z + 2k_2\pi i]$$
$$z^{w_1+w_2} = e^{(w_1+w_2) \log z} = \exp[(w_1+w_2)(\ln|z| + iArg z + 2m\pi i]$$
$$z^{w_1}\cdot z^{w_2} = e^{w_1 \log z}\cdot e^{w_2 \log z}=$$  $$\exp[w_1(\ln|z| + iArg z + 2k_1\pi i] \cdot \exp[w_2(\ln|z| + iArg z + 2k_2\pi i]=$$
$$\exp[(w_1 + w_2)(\ln |z| + iArg z)]\cdot \exp[(w_1 k_1 + w_2k_2)(2\pi i)]$$

We can see that,

$z^{w_1 + w_2} = z^{w_1}\cdot z^{w_2} \iff 2(w_1+w_2)m\pi i +2k\pi i=(w_1k_1 + w_2k_2)(2\pi i)$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$
$$\iff (w_1+w_2)m +k = (w_1k_1 + w_2k_2)$$
$$\iff k = w_1(k_1-m)+w_2(k_2-m)$$

Comment: The statement as written down cannot hold, at least not iff. Take $w_1$, $w_2$ to be independent real numbers, say, $1$ and $\sqrt2$, and $k_1=1=k_2$; there are no integers $k,m$ which make the second equation true, yet the first equation is true (for $z=e$).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531618/finding-conditions-for-which-zw-1zw-2-zw-1w-2-is-satisfied-and-ho?rq=1

Comment: I see, op's approach is the same as mine. thanks for the link.